# How to create KMS asymmetric signing key resource with Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

I've tried the following resource in my template:

```
  SigningKey:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      Description: "Auth API signing key"
      Enabled: true
      # Grant all permissions for root account
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Id: "key-default-1"
        Statement:
          -
            Sid: "Enable IAM User Permissions"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              - AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
            Action: "kms:*"
            Resource: "*"
      EnableKeyRotation: true
      KeyUsage: SIGN_VERIFY
```

But this gives an error:

> The operation failed because the KeyUsage value of the CMK is
>   SIGN_VERIFY. To perform this operation, the KeyUsage value must be
>   ENCRYPT_DECRYPT.

It's also unclear where to specify the key type (eg. `RSA_2048`) in the template from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html).

Comment: Are you sure this error message is caused by the `AWS::KMS::Key` resource and not by another resource defined in the same template?

Comment: @Dunedan yes, the error event specifially references the `SigningKey` resource

Comment: You'd have to specify a keyspec to be an asymmetric type (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/symmetric-asymmetric.html#cmk-key-spec), however, it appears that cloudformation currently doesn't support specifying the keyspec (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html)

Comment: Added a CloudFormation feature request, please upvote if you need it: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html#cfn-kms-key-keyspec), you specify key type in `KeySpec` field. You can also see what types are currently supported in the document. Also, AWS KMS does not support automatic key rotation on asymmetric CMKs. For asymmetric CMKs, omit the EnableKeyRotation property or set it to false.
Above doc also has example to create asymmetric CMKs that you can refer.

Comment: Great it seems the feature request has been shipped: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/337